# Are there invertible functions such that $f=\frac{g}{h}$ and $f^{-1}=\frac{g^{-1}}{h^{-1}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, examples-counterexamples, inverse-function

**Note:** this question is inspired by this one: [Why $\arctan x$ not equal to $\arcsin(x)/\arccos(x)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3744439/why-arctan-x-not-equal-to-arcsinx-arccosx/3744513?noredirect=1#comment7701244_3744513)

In the linked question, it is said that if $f=\frac{g}{h}$ and $f$, $g$ and $h$ are invertible, then $f^{-1}\neq \frac{g^{-1}}{h^{-1}}$ in general. This is clear that it is almost always the case after considering a few examples, but it may be possible that there exists invertible functions $f$, $g$ and $h$ such that $f=\frac{g}{h}$ and $f^{-1}=\frac{g^{-1}}{h^{-1}}$.

I tried a few functions (linear functions, exponentials,...) but without an example.

**Are there any functions satisfying the above property?**

Mastrem's comment shows that a trivial solution exists with $f=g=h=id:\{1\}\to\{1\}$. I am looking for a non-trivial example. Functions can have any domain and codomain, including finite ones, as soon as they have more than one point.

Comment: You should give information about domain and range  of the  functions.

Comment: To expand on that: $\arctan : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is not a two-sided inverse to $\tan$. While it is true that $\tan \circ \arctan$ is the identity function, $\arctan \circ \tan$ can't even be a function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ because $\tan$ isn't defined everywhere and $\arctan$ isn't surjective! However, $\arctan : \mathbb{R} \to (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ is the inverse of $\tan : (-\pi/2, \pi/2) \to \mathbb{R}$. So, the domain and codomain of the functions matters.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk: good remark. The other question is just the inspiration of this one.

Comment: As long as domain and codomain are not further specified let all three be the identity $\{1\}\to\{1\}$.

Comment: @Mastrem: I was waiting before specifying the domain. I would prefer functions with domain and codomain intervals (or union of intervals) of $\mathbb R$, but I was thinking it may be easier to construct an example with finite domains. Your example shows that the question is more interesting if the domains have more than one point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to create examples of this phenomenon is to find an invertible function $f$ such that $g(x)=f(x)f^{-1}(x)$ is its own inverse, and then take $h(x) = f^{-1}(x)$. For example, here is one construction on the six-point domain $\{\frac13,\frac12,\frac23,\frac32,2,3\}$ where $g(x)=x$:
\begin{align*}
f(\tfrac13) &= \tfrac23  &  g(\tfrac13) &= \tfrac13  &  h(\tfrac13) &= \tfrac12 \\
f(\tfrac12) &= \tfrac13  &  g(\tfrac12) &= \tfrac12  &  h(\tfrac12) &= \tfrac32 \\
f(\tfrac23) &= 2 &  g(\tfrac23) &= \tfrac23  &  h(\tfrac23) &= \tfrac13 \\
f(\tfrac32) &= \tfrac12  &  g(\tfrac32) &= \tfrac32  &  h(\tfrac32) &= 3\\
f(2) &= 3 &  g(2) &= 2 &  h(2) &= \tfrac23 \\
f(3) &= \tfrac32  &  g(3) &= 3 &  h(3) &= 2
\end{align*}